# Disable clickhere link in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce-component

I have scenario like, I am displaying link in every row of the
 page block table. But I need to disable the link based on two conditions. 
If any of them is true, I like to disable it. can any one please suggest me . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The standard `<apex:outputLink>` component has a `disabled` attribute exactly for this purpose.

> *disabled*
>
> A Boolean value that specifies whether this link is displayed in a
>   disabled state. If set to true, the field appears disabled because an
>   HTML span tag is used in place of the normal anchor tag. If not
>   specified, this value defaults to false.

You use it like so, where `condition1` and `condition2` are booleans set in your controller:

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.salesforce.com" disabled="{!condition1 || condition2}">www.salesforce.com</apex:outputLink>
```

See the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) on the component.